# Integrals that require multiple applications of the change of variable formula

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, change-of-variable

> Define $T(u,v)=(u^2-v^2,2uv)$. Let $D^*$ be the set of $(u,v)$ with $u^2+v^2\leq1,u\geq0,v\geq0$. Find $T(D^*)=D$. Evaluate $\iint_D dxdy$.

We know $D^*=\{(\cos t,\sin t): 0\leq t\leq\pi/2\}$ the fourth part of the unit circle in the first quadrant. Therefore $T(D^*)=T(\cos t, \sin t) =(\cos 2t, \sin 2t)$ extends $D^*$ to cover the whole upper part of the unit circle.

Since $\textbf{D}T= \begin{pmatrix} 2u & -2v \\ 2v & 2u\end{pmatrix}$, the Jacobian determinant is $4u^2+4v^2$ which is only zero at a boundary point of the region of integration (a measure zero set; irrelevant for integration).

Hence, we define

$$\int_0^1 \int_0^{\sqrt{1-v^2}} 4u^2 + 4v^2 dudv \stackrel{\text{substitutions...}}{=} \frac{4}{3} \int_0^1 (1-v^2)^{3/2}dv$$

Now I don't know how to find this integral.

Do I have to map $D^*$ first to polar coordinates and then find its image under $T$? This would mean computing two Jacobians, right?

I'm really lost.

Comment: As a small formality, the $D^*$ you've defined is not correct since it is only a curve, not a region with area. Once you have the Jacobian going from $(x,y)$ to $(u,v)$, forget the fact that $(u,v)$ was a change of variables and pretend it was the integral you started with. Convert to polar coordinates from $(u,v)$, not $(x,y)$

Comment: @NinadMunshi So... I can just assume $\int_0^1 \int_0^{\sqrt{1-v^2}} 4u^2 4v^2 dudv = \int_0^{\pi /2} \int_0^1 4r^3 dr d\theta$?

Comment: Yes that is correct, I know what you meant

Answer (score 1):

To do the integral, make the substitution $v=\sin\phi.$ Then it takes the form $$\int_0^{π/2}{\cos^4\phi\mathrm d \phi}.$$ To do this, note that $\cos^4\phi-\sin^4\phi=\cos 2\phi$ and $$\cos^4\phi+\sin^4\phi=\frac34+\frac14\cos 4\phi.$$